# GHMM - Attempted m_free on NULL pointer

Tags: python, c, malloc, hidden-markov-models

I'm trying to use the ghmm python module on mac osx with Python 2.7.  I've managed to get everything installed, and I can import ghmm in the python environment, but there are errors when I run this (from the ghmm 'tutorial') (UnfairCasino can be found here http://ghmm.sourceforge.net/UnfairCasino.py):

```
from ghmm import *
from UnfairCasino import test_seq
sigma = IntegerRange(1,7)
A = [[0.9, 0.1], [0.3, 0.7]]
efair = [1.0 / 6] * 6
eloaded = [3.0 / 13, 3.0 / 13, 2.0 / 13, 2.0 / 13, 2.0 / 13, 1.0 / 13]
B = [efair, eloaded]
pi = [0.5] * 2
m = HMMFromMatrices(sigma, DiscreteDistribution(sigma), A, B, pi)
v = m.viterbi(test_seq)
```

Specifically I get this error:

> GHMM ghmm.py:148 - sequence.c:ghmm_dseq_free(1199): Attempted m_free on NULL pointer. Bad program, BAD! No cookie for you.
>   python(52313,0x7fff70940cc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x74706d6574744120: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   Abort trap

and when I set the ghmm.py logger to "DEBUG", the log prints out the following just before:

> GHMM ghmm.py:2333 - HMM.viterbi() -- begin
>
> GHMM ghmm.py:849 - EmissionSequence.asSequenceSet() -- begin  >
>
> GHMM ghmm.py:862 - EmissionSequence.asSequenceSet() -- end  >
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/logging/**init**.py", line 842, in emit
>
> msg = self.format(record)
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/logging/**init**.py", line 719, in format
>
> return fmt.format(record)
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/logging/**init**.py", line 464, in format
>
> record.message = record.getMessage()
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/logging/**init**.py", line 328, in getMessage
>
> msg = msg % self.args
>
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
>
> Logged from file ghmm.py, line 1159
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/logging/**init**.py", line 842, in emit
>
> msg = self.format(record)
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/logging/**init**.py", line 719, in format
>
> return fmt.format(record)
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/logging/**init**.py", line 464, in format
>
> record.message = record.getMessage()
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/logging/**init**.py", line 328, in getMessage
>
> msg = msg % self.args
>
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
>
> Logged from file ghmm.py, line 949
>
> GHMM ghmm.py:2354 - HMM.viterbi() -- end
>
> GHMM ghmm.py:1167 - **del** SequenceSubSet  >

So I suspect it has something to do with the way Sequences are deleted once the Viterbi function is completed, but I'm not sure if this means I need to modify the Python code, the C code, or if I need to compile ghmm and the wrappers differently.  Any help/suggestions would be appreciated greatly as I have been trying to get this library to work the last 4 days.

Answer (score 3):

Given the age of this question, you've probably moved onto something else, but this seemed to be the only related result I found.  The issue is that a double-free is happening, due to some weirdness in how the python function 'EmissionSequence::asSequenceSet' is executed.  If you look at how ghmm.py is implemented (~lines 845 - 863)

```
def asSequenceSet(self):
    """
    @returns this EmissionSequence as a one element SequenceSet
    """
    log.debug("EmissionSequence.asSequenceSet() -- begin " + repr(self.cseq))
    seq = self.sequenceAllocationFunction(1)

    # checking for state labels in the source C sequence struct
    if self.emissionDomain.CDataType == "int" and self.cseq.state_labels is not None:
        log.debug("EmissionSequence.asSequenceSet() -- found labels !")
        seq.calloc_state_labels()
        self.cseq.copyStateLabel(0, seq, 0)

    seq.setLength(0, self.cseq.getLength(0))
    seq.setSequence(0, self.cseq.getSequence(0))
    seq.setWeight(0, self.cseq.getWeight(0))

    log.debug("EmissionSequence.asSequenceSet() -- end " + repr(seq))
    return SequenceSetSubset(self.emissionDomain, seq, self)
```

This should probably raise some red flags, since it seems to be reaching into the C a bit much (not that I know for sure, I haven't looked to far into it).

Anyways, if you look a little above this function, there is another function called 'sequenceSet':

```
def sequenceSet(self):
    """
    @return a one-element SequenceSet with this sequence.
    """

    # in order to copy the sequence in 'self', we first create an empty SequenceSet and then
    # add 'self'
    seqSet = SequenceSet(self.emissionDomain, [])
    seqSet.cseq.add(self.cseq)
    return seqSet
```

It seems that it has the same purpose, but is implemented differently.  Anyways, if you replace the body of 'EmissionSequence::asSequenceSet' in ghmm.py, with just:

```
def asSequenceSet(self):
"""
@returns this EmissionSequence as a one element SequenceSet
"""
    return self.sequenceSet();
```

And then rebuild/reinstall the ghmm module, the code will work without crashing, and you should be able to go on your merry way.  I'm not sure if this can be submitted as a fix, since the ghmm project looks a little dead, but hopefully this is simple enough to help anyone in dire straights using this library.